# Insert into w/ multiple selects giving ERROR 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: insert-into, mysql-error-1242

I have table foo1 with columns UserID,TimeStamp; foo2 with columns userID,Level & table foo3 with columns userID,Timestamp.

I want to INSERT into foo1 all rows from foo3 where the UserID exists in table foo2.

I am getting ERROR 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row  with the following

```
INSERT into foo1 (UserID,TimeStamp)
SELECT  
(SELECT UserID from foo2 as UserID),

(SELECT foo3.TimeStamp
from foo3
inner join foo2
ON foo3.UserID=foo2.UserID) as TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to INSERT into foo1 all rows from foo3 where the UserID exists in table foo2 then you should go through this:

```
INSERT into foo1 (UserID,TimeStamp)
SELECT foo3.UserID,foo3.TimeStamp
from foo3
inner join foo2
ON foo3.UserID=foo2.UserID
```